# Add The Value of All Rows in a Text File?

Tags: python, bash, perl, shell, math

I have a text file that looks like this:

```
0,5
3,100
30,90
```

For each row, I need to subtract the value of the first column from the value of the second column and then add 1.  And then add up each row.  For the example above:

```
5-0+1 = 6
100-3+1 = 98
90-30+1 = 61
```

Then I'd just add up those numbers:  `6+98+61 = 165`.

The final result I'm trying to get with this is the number `165`.  As long as the same logic above is followed, I don't really care if it's done in a different way.  I'm just trying to find out the best way.

The text file has about 15 million rows of text.  The second number is always higher than or equal to the first number, so you never have to worry about negatives.

I'd be okay doing this in whatever language would be best, as long as it won't require extra (non-default) modules to be installed.  Any examples would be appreciated as well.

My main concern is that it's processing 15 million rows, I need it to be fast as possible, and I'm not familiar enough with coding languages to know which would be the most efficient.

Comment: You've got two decent answers, but you should really show what you've tried.  How big is the sum likely to be?  You might need to worry about arithmetic overflows.  Also, the calculation is equivalent to sum(col2) - sum(col1) + NumRows.  Whether that's better than the arithmetic on each line depends in part on the values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is off the top of my head, but I think `awk` is a potential solution (assume the numbers are in numbers.txt):

```
awk -F, '{tot += $2 - $1 + 1} END{print tot}' < numbers.txt
```

The `-F,` tells `awk` that comma is a separator, `tot` starts out as 0, by default, `END` is an awk keyword that say to execute the code block that follows after EOF is hit on the data.

Awk is not the fastest weapon in the arsenal, but I'd give it a try as it fits on one line!

Comment: Thanks!  Worked perfect, I'll accept your answer in 3 minutes when it lets me. :)

Comment: Out of curiosity, how long does it take for the 15M rows? (You can put `time` in front of the command to get the timing.)

Comment: It was much, much faster than I expected: `real - 0m 0.134s, user - 0m 0.131s, sys - 0m 0.003s`

Comment: Excellent!  Happy to help.

Answer (score 1):

In perl, I'd do it like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $sum;
while ( <> ) { 
   m/(\d+),(\d+)/;
   $sum += $2 - $1 + 1;
}
print $sum;
```

Which one-liner-ifies as;

```
perl -F',' -lane '$sum += $F[1] - $F[0] + 1; END { print $sum }'
```